# How to store 1000 lines and after to execute the batch?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert to database a huge amount of data (a few millions of lines) and I want to do it using "batches" . So, I have o method which receives let's say 1000 lines from a csv and it will execute the batch after the for loop iterates over all those 1000 thousand lines and so on. I wrote the method but it seams that it add to database only one line from those 1000.

Here is what I've tried.

```
public void insertToDatabase(List<Account> listOfAccounts, Connection connection){

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try
    {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement( INSERT_ACCOUNT_QUERY );
    }
    catch( SQLException e1 )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {

        for( Account account : listOfAccounts )
        {

            connection.setAutoCommit( false );


            preparedStatement.setString( 1, account.getFirstName( ) );
            preparedStatement.setString( 2, account.getLastName( ) );
            preparedStatement.setInt( 3, account.getHomeTellNumber( ) );
            preparedStatement.setInt( 4, account.getMobileTellNumber( ) );
            preparedStatement.setString( 5, account.getAddress( ) );
            preparedStatement.setString( 6, account.getCity( ) );
            preparedStatement.setString( 7, account.getState( ) );
            preparedStatement.setString( 8, account.getJob( ).getCode( ) );
            preparedStatement.setString( 9, account.getLocale( ).getCode( ) );

            preparedStatement.addBatch( );
        }


        preparedStatement.executeBatch( );

    }

    catch( SQLException e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            preparedStatement.close( );
        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }
}
```

So the method insert to database only the last element from the list instead to add all of them at once, at the end.

Thank you.

Comment: Aside: I don't think you need the `setAutoCommit` on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: And where do you actually make the commit?

Comment: Most RDBMSs have bulk-load utilities, where you load whatever raw file you have onto the server, then process it from there.  Above a certain size, it's faster than what you're doing here (even in batch mode, although that helps).  Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you left auto commit to enabled, your current script should be working.  Since you have set auto commit to false, you have to explicitly commit your update:

```
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
// add the next line
connection.commit();
```

I recommend just leaving auto commit enabled.  If you suspect that your JDBC driver does have this setting by default, then just call the following once, before you hit the loop:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Then, you won't have to explicitly commit your work.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But the problem now is that It inserts to database twice. So, instead 1000 lines it inserts 2000.

Comment: Then I think there is some other problem with your code not shown above.  I am happy to keep working with you to get your code working.